# Not all items in layer-list are showing up

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a view like what's in this link here: https://imgur.com/a/6b75AMp

This is the layer-list I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/HobbesLightGreen"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:left="8dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/HobbesBackground"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">

        // The width and color of the border
           <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#3C341F" />

        // The desired corner radius. reduce it to keep it less rounded
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        <solid
            android:color="#F0ECE0"
            />


        </shape>
    </item>


</layer-list>
```

However, the border doesn't show up. If I play around with the order of the items--for example, if I make the vertical stripe the last item--then the border might show up, but the vertical stripe won't. How do I get everything in the layer-list to show up properly?

Comment: just a little thing, comments inside xml works with <!-- and --> (I didn't have any problem using // but I got some warnings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following code you will get a hint

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/HobbesLightGreen" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:left="4dp" android:top="4dp" android:right="4dp" android:bottom="4dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/HobbesBackground" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:left="8dp" android:top="8dp" android:right="8dp" android:bottom="8dp">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">

        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#3C341F" />
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        <solid android:color="#F0ECE0" />

    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified some of your code, use it and chech the output.

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:left="8dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        <stroke android:color="#000000" android:width="2dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```